# Storing jpg data in dictionary?

Tags: python, image, data-structures

I have a camera that takes records two images per minute, resulting in 2880 images per day at ~180kb/image. Over a period of several months this adds up to many images, which makes transferring the data cumbersome. To get around this I tar the images into monthly tar files (e.g. 201301.tar, 201302.tar). I use the images in my analysis work, so I do need access to the data, and I hit two problems:

1. To load an individual jpg I need to un-tar the month's images (I would like to avoid the time involved in un-taring)
2. Reading in individual jpg's is slow when I have to read in several day's worth of data.

Is there a practical way of storing the image data in a single file (more likely I will store data on a month-by-month basis again)? I think storing as a dictionary (key=datetime value, value=array (size=480 x 660 x 3)) makes sense, but I have issues in re-loading the data.

```
# Example
import datetime as dt
from scipy.misc import imread as ir

dts = dt.datetime.strptime

image = ir('skycam-current.jpg',flatten=False)

data = {}
data[dt.datetime(2013,01,01)] = image
np.savez('test.dic.npz',data)

# Then, to re-load the data
data = np.load('test.dic.npz')
```

When I re-load the data, I get a dictionary, kinda:

```
>>> type(data)
>>> numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile

>>> data.keys()
>>> ['arr_0']
```

If I try to recover the dictionary, I get a 0-d array

```
>>> a = data['arr_0']
>>> a.shape
>>> ()
```

Can anyone recommend a better method of either storing the dictionary, or storing the image data?  I have been using pandas for my analysis/storage, but it does not seem to be built for storing arrays.

Comment: Have you considered storing it as a bytestring?

Comment: If you switch to a zip format, you'll at least be able to extract individual files - see http://superuser.com/questions/173756/which-is-more-efficient-tar-or-zip-compression-what-is-the-difference-between

Comment: Why don't you use a database

Comment: Database may be a good option, but I have never worked with databases.  I was trying to staw within my realm of experience.

Answer (score 2):

If it's already jpeg compressed, you don't really get much of a space advantage by compressing it further. Are you putting these into tar archives to try to save space, or is it because the directory needs to be human readable? If the directory doesn't need to be human readable, then there isn't much of an advantage archiving vs. just storing each month in a separate folder and using either a sqlite database or just some logic in your file/folder names to keep track of them.

Comment: tar just archives the images, no compression.  I do have the images stored in a well-ordered directory (e.g. /year/month/day/image.jpg).  The problem is loading the image data currently must be done on a file-by-file basis, while I would like to load, e.g. all of Oct-2013, at once.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve by using tar vs. just a directory?

Comment: I only use tar to reduce transfer time between machines and when pushing data to archive.

Comment: Would it work to simply tar it up into some temporary location before you do either of those things? I'm unsure of the performance of tar, but surely it's lower than the overhead of making that many different connections to send the files.

Answer (score 1):

A tar file is a great way to store incompressible files, like jpgs. It's better than using zip, since you don't have de/compression overhead, and probably better than using the filesystem, since you're generating a lot of files. Storing the files in RAM means that you must have a large amount of memory dedicated to the task, and it makes accessing and transferring the data between machines harder.

The big problem with tar files is that they [don't allow random access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29#Random_access), since they're not indexed like zip files. This means that, to extract a file from the middle of a archive, you must read the whole archive until you reach the file.

To work around this limitation, several people have build tar file indexers, that store the offsets to the files in the archive, so that you can read them directly. One such project is [tarindexer](https://github.com/devsnd/tarindexer), which is conveniently written in python, so you can easily use it as a library. It's only 100 lines long, so it'll be easy to understand and adapt, too.

Comment: Entries in a zip file don't have to be compressed.

Comment: I like the idea of a tarindexer.  Thanks for the tip...will look into.